# Tensorflow Serving: Tensor dimension changing upon serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

## Problem

I'm new to serving with Tensorflow (in fact this is my first model that I serve!) so I apologize if the answer is obvious!

I'm hosting a Tensorflow model on docker using this [image](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-tensorflow-serving). The problem is that the server is sending the following error every time I try to send data so that the served model can do predictions.

```
W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at transpose_op.cc:157 : Invalid argument: transpose expects a vector of size 4. But input(1) is a vector of size 3
```

## Background info

1. Using saved_model_cli, the model can be shown as

```
signature_def['predict']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['init_state'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (2, 2, -1, 136)
        name: policy_estimator/lstm/Placeholder:0
    inputs['state'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 136)
        name: policy_estimator/state:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['action_probs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 260)
        name: policy_estimator/Softmax:0
    outputs['final_state'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (2, 2, -1, 136)
        name: policy_estimator/packed:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

2. The model works properly without errors before hosting because I was able to train the model using pre-existing data.
3. The error appears to correspond to the dimension of state. When I change the dimension of the data to pass in to state from 2(which is (-1, 136)) to 3(using np.expand_dims), the error message changes to

```
W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at transpose_op.cc:157 : Invalid argument: transpose expects a vector of size 5. But input(1) is a vector of size 3
```

and when I change the dimension to 4 it changes to

```
W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at transpose_op.cc:157 : Invalid argument: transpose expects a vector of size 6. But input(1) is a vector of size 3
```

However, when I make it 1 dimension, the error message remains as

```
W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at transpose_op.cc:157 : Invalid argument: transpose expects a vector of size 4. But input(1) is a vector of size 3
```

4. The server is running properly as I get

```
{
 "model_version_status": [
  {
   "version": "1",
   "state": "AVAILABLE",
   "status": {
    "error_code": "OK",
    "error_message": ""
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

when I run `curl http://model:8501/v1/models/saved_model` where `http://model:8501/v1/models/saved_model` is where the model is hosted.

5. I request to the model using python by

```
payload = [{"init_state":np.reshape(initial_state, (2,2,-1,136)).tolist(), "state": np.reshape(points, (-1, 136)).tolist()}]
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "predict", "instances":payload})
r = requests.post('http://model:8501/v1/models/saved_model:predict', data=data, headers=headers)
```

following [this documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/tutorials/Serving_REST_simple). Where r is the response. In this case, this r returns a response of 400.

## Personal conclusion

The only conclusion I could draw from this was that there may have been a change in the model upon serving it. However, this is just speculation since I'm stuck and am not sure about the next step.

I'm no professional so again, I apologize if I am missing something obvious! Please humor me. If any information is missing please notify me as I'll do my best to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json
.
.
.
payload = {"init_state":np.reshape(initial_state, (2,2,-1,136)).tolist(),"state": np.reshape(points, (-1, 136)).tolist()}
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "predict", "inputs":payload})
# add this
data = json.loads(data) # apparently json.dumps returns a json string: '{}' not a json object: {} 

r = requests.post('http://model:8501/v1/models/saved_model:predict', json=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer but while the server stopped showing any messages, it still responds with the message handler error(error code 400). I suspect that the data was not able to get to the server anymore? I don't know backend that much so I'm not sure though.

Comment: You may also consider reading the TensorFlow Serving documentation [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest) to know whether to use: `data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "predict", "instances":payload})` OR `data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "predict", "inputs":payload})`

Comment: Thanks! Hmm... I can see why using inputs instead of instances make sense after reading the documentation. But I wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: Only the response of 400. The server stopped showing errors in the server log.